# How to check if python file is already running?

Tags: python, file, server, client

I am working on client-server project using Tkinter GUI, and I want to check if ChatServer.py is running before I am running ChatClient.py file.

for example:

I want to run the `Client().runGUI()` line **only** if ChatServer.py is running, else I want to print an message to the terminal.

```
def runGUI(self):
   self.window.mainloop()


Client().runGUI()
```

I have no access to the server, so I cant check if is running or not, my main question is if **I can run a line of code only if ChatServer.py is already running.**

[Pic of my current python files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsDgH.png)

Comment: Is the server and the client running on the same machine?

Comment: Why not try connecting to the server - with a timeout? If it raises an error then the server isn't running. Another method would be to check if a python process is executing the client code if the server is on the same machine

Comment: If you have no access to the server what's the point of knowing whether it's up or not?

Comment: @TheLizzard i would like to hear more about that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the server and the client are running on the same machine. An easy approach is to create a lock file. Basically, the server creates the file when it is run, then deletes the file when it ends. This way, one can always know if the process is running. Here's an example of what the server should do:

```py
import atexit
import os
import tempfile
import sys

# Create the file. If it already exists (the server is already running), then
# this fails and the program stops here.
lock = open(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/chatserver.lock', 'x')
lock.close()


# Function to delete the lock.
def removeLock():
    os.remove(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/chatserver.lock')


atexit.register(removeLock)

#
# Main server code
#

# Put this at the end of the program, or whatever code is run when the program
# is about to end.
removeLock()
```

Then, in the client all you have to do is check if the file exists. Like this:

```py
import os
import tempfile

if os.path.exists(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/chatserver.lock'):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I think `if os.path.exists(...)` is better.

Comment: Thanks, '/tmp/chatserver.lock' it is the path file? what is 'x' also? i am getting error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/chatserver.lock' @MichaelM.

Comment: `/tmp/chatserver.lock` is just an arbitrary path so you can change it to whatever you want, but `/tmp` is the traditional directory for temporary files (like locks) on Linux. The `x` mode means create the file or panic if it already exists.

Comment: @Roee Regarding your error message, are you on Windows? If so, then you may need to change the path `/tmp/chatserver.lock` to something else.

Comment: Any suggestions to what to change maybe? @MichaelM.

Comment: @Roee Just use `"chatserver.lock"` - without the `/tmp/`. That wasy it's easier to manually delete it, if something happens.

Comment: @Roee I've just updated my answer to use python's `tmpfile`. This code should work on Windows too. Does it work for you?

Comment: @TheLizzard If `ChatServer.py` and `ChatClient.py` are run in different directories, then `"chatserver.lock"` will be mean two different files. Generally, it is better to keep temporary files in a designated temporary file directory.

Comment: @MichaelM. True in most cases, but right now they are both in the same dir - look at the linked image in the question. Also there can be cases where the lock isn't deleted so OP will have to manually delete the lock.

Comment: Ok its works good! but when I close the server the ChatServer.lock file is not deleted

Comment: @Roee How are you closing the server?

Comment: @Roee I've updated my code to use python's `atexit`. Now the lock file should be removed whenever the program ends.

Comment: so with tempfile.gettempdir() after few accesses to the server is said that the file already exists so I delated that and stay only with 'chatserver.lock' its look like he create the file in the program directory @MichaelM. thanks for helping

Comment: So the problem is if I stop the server by Stop Ctrl+f2, the file is not delated any ideas why? @MichaelM.

Comment: how do you stop it with `Ctrl+F2`? Do you run it in some `IDE`? IDE may run it in separated thread and it can kill thread and script may not have time to run `atexit`.

Comment: as I remember some programs may also write its `Process ID` inside .lock file - so next execution may also get `Process ID` from file and check in system if this process is still running.